# 30-40 second delay in pushing iOS notifications using AWS SNS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

We are using AWS SNS and APNS to send notifications to iOS (Swift) from a Ruby on Rails server. The notifications are going through to iOS but taking about 30-40 seconds which is unacceptable for our app. We can send test notifications using the AWS console that go through immediately, so it doesn't look like an iOS error. In the logs, we can see the notification hitting AWS and returning a 200 response. So it looks like the delay is between AWS and iOS. How can we make these notifications go through more quickly?

```
notification = {
  :aps => {
    "mutable-content" => 1,
    :category => category,
    :sound => "default",
    :extra => data
  }
}

notification[:aps][:alert] = { :title => title, :body => body } if title

sns_message = {
  :APNS_SANDBOX => notification.to_json,
  :APNS         => notification.to_json
}
config = YAML.load(File.read(Rails.root.join('config', 'aws.yml')))[Rails.env]
sns = AWS::SNS::Client.new(
  :access_key_id     => config['access_key_id'    ],
  :secret_access_key => config['secret_access_key'],
  :region            => config['region'           ]
)
sns.publish(
  :target_arn => self.arn,
  :message => sns_message.to_json,
  :message_structure => 'json'
)
```

Comment: Have you used service extention in your iOS app? If so, can you post your code for it, coz recently I have made one error which was causing standard notification to come with a delay.

Comment: @manishsharma93 I removed the service extension and that eliminated the delay. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome:) In future if you want to use service extension, make sure to implement proper completion handler for all conditions in "didReceiveNotificationRequest" method of service extension.